# Can I upgrade my .net 4.8 webforms webapp to .net 5.0?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have a medium-sized Web Application project on Framework 4.8.  It has Webforms and MVC (and webapi) in it. I am confused by the recent 5.0 announcements that seem to indicate that everything should now be 5.0.  After downloading the new SDK, and Visual Studio 16.8 preview4, I am still not able to change the target framework of my main webapp project in its settings. Am I missing a step? Can I upgrade my .net 4.8 app to 5.0?

Comment: Web Forms is not included in .NET 5. Web Forms is dying/dead. That's a good thing. It's a good excuse for you to not keep maintaining such an old application. It's your chance to re-do it with a modern architecture.

Comment: You have a world of options available to you. MVC would be the most straightforward upgrade since you're using it elsewhere in your app. Rewrite all the Web Forms functionality into MVC on the old ASP.NET, then upgrade to ASP.NET Core running on .NET 5 should be pretty straightforward. But you could also do Razor Pages, or Web API combined with a front end framework like Blazor, Angular, React, Vue etc.

Comment: why did you not put this in as an answer, since you know the answer is "no"?

Comment: Was trying to find something more official than just my knowledge of the situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Web Forms is not included in .NET 5. You will have to eliminate Web Forms from your application if you want to upgrade to .NET 5.

Rich Lander (Program Manager on the .NET team at Microsoft) [explicitly pointed this out on Twitter](https://twitter.com/runfaster2000/status/1125459930041933824).
[image: Screenshot of Rich lander saying Web Forms will not be in .NET 5, via Twitter]

Comment: For new projects, use [ASP.NET Razor Pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio),  [Did ASP.NET Web Forms Need to Die?](https://medium.com/young-coder/did-asp-net-web-forms-need-to-die-4b7bce958aaa)

Comment: @JavierCañon I don't necessarily agree that Razor Pages should be a standard recommendation. It's an option, but there's plenty of other great options such as Blazor, MVC, a SPA with Angular/React/Vue/etc. Rather than picking any one, I would encourage whoever is trying to figure out what to do to research their options and pick the one that best matches their needs.

Comment: Yes you can use any technology... but the question its about Web Forms, so you assume that the programmer know very well the Web Forms, the most logical learning path is Razor Pages, buts... maybe depent of the type of project, [asp-net-razor-pages-vs-mvc](https://stackify.com/asp-net-razor-pages-vs-mvc/)

Comment: @JavierCañon They also said they had MVC in the app. Knowing that, I'd much rather migrate my Web Forms to ASP.NET MVC over time, and then I can upgrade to ASP.NET Core MVC at my leisure.